Why `satisfies` is required only for objects and not for simple types?
Shouldn't I get the same error? It's the same situation, assigning a function to a number | Function type and calling it:
type Treta = {
    name: string,
    stuff: number | Function
}

const obj1 = {
    name: "Paulo",
    stuff: () => {}
} satisfies Treta;

obj1.stuff() // No error!

const obj2: Treta = {
    name: "Paulo",
    stuff: () => {}
};

obj2.stuff();
//  ^^^^ ERROR: No constituent of type 'number | Function' is callable.

type Other = number | Function;

const obj3 : Other = () => {};

obj3(); // No error even without satisfies

TS Playground link

I got no error when running it JsFiddle

Hi @Mippy, sorry I should have said it's was a type checking error, not an actual execution error, I added the playground link

TS does assignment narrowing if the type assigned to is a union. In obj1, satisfies just checks the type, it doesn't widen it, so obj1.stuff is known to be a function and has nothing to do with narrowing. In obj2, you are annotating the type as Treta which isn't a union, so there's no narrowing; TS forgets that obj2.stuff is a function. In obj3 you are annotating as Other, which is a union, so it narrows. Does this fully address the q? If so I'll write an a; if not, what's missing?

HI @jcalz, it does! Feel free to write the answer, thank you!

In
const obj1 = {
    name: "Paulo",
    stuff: () => {}
} satisfies Treta;

obj1.stuff() // okay

you're using the satisfies operator, which doesn't widen the type of the expression to Treta, it just checks that the expression is assignable to the it.  So obj1 is of type  {name: string, stuff: () => void}, and stuff is known to be callable.

In
const obj2: Treta = {
    name: "Paulo",
    stuff: () => {}
};

obj2.stuff(); // error!

you have annotated the type of ob2 to be Treta, which is a single object type.  And therefore, ob2 is widened all the way to Treta, and any more specific information found in the initializing object is thrown away.  So obj2 is of type Treta, and its stuff property is not known to be callable.

In
type Other = number | Function;    
const obj3: Other = () => {};    
obj3(); // okay

you've annotated obj3 as a union type. And in that case, when you assign a value to it, you get assignment narrowing, where obj3 is narrowed to just the member(s) of the union compatible with the assigned value. In this case, it's Function, so obj3 is seen as type Function when you call it, and it's fine.
Note well that assignment narrowing only happens when you're assigning to a variable of a union type.  Treta is not a union (even though its stuff property is a union) so assignment narrowing does not happen.
